# Argument 'PostCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I've looked at about 10 answers to similar questions, and still can't figure this one out.

I'm trying to add some Angular to a preexisting Rails app I have, and started by following [these tips](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/).

So I have this in my app:

**application.coffee**

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require bootstrap
#= require libraries/angular.min
#= require libraries/angular-resource.min
#= require_tree .
#= require main-ng
```

then this

**main-ng.coffee**

```
#= require_tree ./controllers

angular.module('Posts', [])

@MainApp = angular.module("MainApp", [
  # modules the app depends on -- this is all I've got so far.
  "Posts"
])
```

In **layouts/application.html.haml** this is all I have relating to angular:

```
%html{ 'ng-app' => "MainApp" }
```

For some reason, doing `ng_app: 'MainApp'` didn't work here, though that syntax seems to work elsewhere (and has in other established apps with Angular I've coded in).

Then there's just the view with the controller:

**posts/show.html.haml**

```
.row.container{ ng_controller: 'PostCtrl' }
# Using hashrocket syntax brings up the same error, while misspelling it does nothing, 
# so this syntax appears to be working here
```

and finally, the controller:

**controllers/PostCtrl.coffee**

```
#= require directives/markdown

postModule = angular.module("Posts", ["markdown"])
console.log postModule # returns angular object on page load

ctrl = postModule.controller "PostCtrl", ($scope, $http, $location) -> 

  $s = $scope

  console.log 'Inside controller' # doesn't get hit

console.log ctrl # returns angular object on page load
```

Any ideas what noobish error I'm committing here? I've hit a wall here.

Possible clue -- changing the name of the controller in the view changes the name in the error, but none of the console logs, so it basically seems to be an error finding that particular controller.

Another thing of note -- requiring the js controllers directory in my main-ng.coffee file and declaring the controller on the MainApp module instead of the Posts module both don't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your Post module declared twice

`angular.module('Posts', [])`

and

`postModule = angular.module("Posts", ["markdown"])`

I suggest copy the second one and replace first. Then remove the second module.

Both these syntax create new module so the one added earlier is overridden.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. That's weird, cause we definitely used that double-declaration syntax in the other app I've used Angular with. I'll have to ask how it works there. At any rate, appreciate that. Saved me some major headaches.